# 'Failed to load resource' after adding new controller

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have already added 2 controllers in my Web API, StudentsController and AuthenticateController, and  and everything is working as it should. When I go to http://localhost:64792/api/students, it prints the default: ["value1","value2"]

The problem is when I add a third controller, nothing works anymore. When i go to the same URL, I get the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Are you limited to 2 controllers only, or what am I missing here?